# Directories disappear and reappear in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, permissions, directory, raid

I have a really odd issue with Ubuntu 16.04 (Server). I have a hardware-RAID working in my Ubuntu Server (HP Microserver Gen10), that's containing my backups in several directories. Everything worked fine. Till I determined that some of my folders, that I recently created disappear an reappear from boot to boot. I haven't found a way to reproduce the situation. I'm owner and member of the specific folders and groups and have the correct privileges (755) for them. Even listing the folders as root don't make them visible till the next or the following boot process. Has anyone an idea what is going on here?

Comment: Try looking in `dmesg` for mount/other filesystem errors. If you see anything odd, you could add it to your question.

Comment: @NonnyMoose: Seems to be fine. What do you think?
[ 3.946044] sdb: sdb1 [ 7.715204] XFS (sdb1): Mounting V5 Filesystem 
[ 7.876471] XFS (sdb1): Ending clean mount 
[ 7.681342] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, no debug enabled 
[ 7.715204] XFS (sdb1): Mounting V5 Filesystem [ 7.876471] XFS (sdb1): Ending clean mount

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. I think I was unclear in my previous comment, however; I meant that you should do that when you notice that the directories are missing.

Comment: @NonnyMoose: Unfortunately that's the result when some but not all folders are "hidden". Especially "old" folders (created months ago) never vanish. I guess this will be a hard case.. :-/

Answer (score 2):

### Solution: Finally I have found a hint for the cause of this issue in the syslog:

---

`systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2dpartuuid-0b1dc9a4\x2d417e\x2d4618\x2d879e\x2d406ceb613bb2.device: 
Dev dev-disk-by\x2dpartuuid-0b1dc9a4\x2d417e\x2d4618\x2d879e\x2d406ceb613bb2.device appeared twice with different sysfs paths /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:01:00.0/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1 and /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:01:00.0/ata3/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdc/sdc1`

---

Solution was, that the RAID1 became inconsistent and so with every boot only 1 (Virtual) HDD was mounted and their content became deviant by the time. I could then see in the RAID-Setup of BIOS, that there were 2 Virtual Disks instead of one! RAID1-Array. I think that the Marvell 88SE9230 SATA controller did not tolerate the last BIOS-Update very well. Next time when I update BIOS I will perform better checks afterwards.